# CSS Transform displaces div child contents

Tags: html, css, animation, transform, css-transforms

When I animate divs without using transform, everything works as expected. When I add a transform to the containing div, the inner divs are displaced to the right of the containing div.

```css
html,body
{
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 width: 1920px;
 height: 1080px;
}
.container
{
 width: 1920px;
 height: 1080px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.bottom-container
{
 float: left;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 width: 1920px;
 height: 135px;
 align-content: center;
 position: relative;
}
.b-holder
{
 background-color: rgba(255,255,0,.4);
 justify-content: center;
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: 135px;
 animation-name: b-holder-a;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 position: fixed;
 left: 560px;
 top: 945px;
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes b-holder-a
{
 0%
 {
  top: 1080px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
 }
 20%
 {
  top: 945px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 80%
 {
  top: 945px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
 100%
 {
  top: 1080px;
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
.b-left
{
 background-color: rgba(100,0,0,0.6);
 display: inline-block;
 margin: none;
 padding: none;
 height: 135px;
 width: 246px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 714px;
 animation-name: b-left-a;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 color: #fff;
}
@-webkit-keyframes b-left-a
{
 0%
 {
  left: 745px;
 }
 20%
 {
  left: 745px;
 }
 40%
 {
  left: 560px;
 }
 60%
 {
  left: 560px;
 }
 80%
 {
  left: 745px;
 }
 100%
 {
  left: 745px;
 }
}
.b-center
{
 background-color: rgba(0,100,0,.2);
 display: inline-block;
 width: 308px;
 margin: none;
 padding: none;
 height: 135px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 806px;
 color: #fff;
}
.b-right
{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,100,0.6);
 display: inline-block;
 margin: none;
 padding: none;
 float: right;
 height: 135px;
 width: 246px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 960px;
 animation-name: b-right-a;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 background-position: right;
 color: #fff;
}
@-webkit-keyframes b-right-a
{
 0%
 {
  left: 926px;
 }
 20%
 {
  left: 926px;
 }
 40%
 {
  left: 1114px;
 }
 60%
 {
  left: 1114px;
 }
 80%
 {
  left: 926px;
 }
 100%
 {
  left: 926px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="bottom-container">
  <div class="b-holder">
   <div class="b-left">
    LEFT
   </div>
   <div class="b-right">
    RIGHT
   </div>
   <div class="b-center">
    CENTER
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If the transform is removed from b-holder-a all divs are positioned properly. What causes this to happen? How do I get the left right and center divs to stay absolutely positioned when a transform is added to the containing divs animation?

Note: this is specifically crafted for Chrome browsers

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when a transform is added, the contents of the div use Absolute positioning instead of Fixed positioning. I solved this by changing the left values for each animation.